# Cannot enlarge string buffer containing 1073741779 bytes by 596 more bytes while reading from PGReplicationStream in java

Tags: java, postgresql, wal, logical-replication

I am running into the following problem.

I want read WAL in postgres database using logical replication and wal2json plugin, Could you please help me how to resolve this issue?

Also I observed that the replication slots after some time became inactive.

Thanks.

```
ByteBuffer buffer = PGReplicationStream.read() gives following error.

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: out of memory
 Detail: Cannot enlarge string buffer containing 1073741779 bytes by 596 more bytes.
 Where: slot "tempslot", output plugin "wal2json", in the change callback, associated LSN 1/5781D4B0
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2468)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processCopyResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1144)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readFromCopy(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1063)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.CopyDualImpl.readFromCopy(CopyDualImpl.java:37)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.replication.V3PGReplicationStream.receiveNextData(V3PGReplicationStream.java:155)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.replication.V3PGReplicationStream.readInternal(V3PGReplicationStream.java:124)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.replication.V3PGReplicationStream.read(V3PGReplicationStream.java:70)
```

Comment: You're reading 1GB of data into memory and running out of memory. You can resolve the issue with either more memory or reading less data.

Comment: where should I configure this

Comment: With the normal `-Xmx` heap options. But if your WAL records are 1GB+ in size, you'll be in a "heap" of trouble.

Answer (score -2):

The database server is running out of memory, probably processing a large item of data. Increase memory on the server side, or reduce memory consumption (`work_mem`, `shared_buffers`, `max_connections`).